# Python: iterating over a list range without duplicating it

Tags: python, list, indexing, iterator

Suppose that I have the list `list_1` and that I want to iterate over its elements from indices `i` to `(j - 1)`, where `j > i`.

My options, as I know them are:

**Option 1: Constructing a whole new list**

```
for element in list_1[i:j]:
    # do something
```

**Option 2: Iterating over the indices themselves**

```
for index in range(i, j):
    element = list_1[index]
    # do something
```

Both options are not desirable. The first option is not desirable because it involves construction of a new list. The second option is not desirable especially in terms of readability, as its iteration is over the indices, rather than over the list elements.

Is there a built-in generator function that iterates over the elements in a given range?

Comment: Sadly ironic that this is a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to iterate over a subset of values, by index:

```
from itertools import islice

for element in islice(list_1, i, j):
```

This will still iterate over all `i - 1` initial values of `list_1`, but will do so in C and not keep skipped values in memory.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> list_1 = [42, 81, 117, 3103, 17, 22]
>>> for elem in islice(list_1, 2, 5):
...     print(elem)
...
117
3103
17
```

Comment: Thanks you. This looks just liked what I hoped to have.

Comment: This `itertools` module seems to be something a Python programmer must learn and master. It is a shame that I don't regularly use it. Is there a usage convention? Is it more common to use `from itertools import <func>` rather than `import itertools as it` and then use `it.<func>()` ?

Comment: @SomethingSomething: I use it like any other standard library module, I don't usually abbreviate module names. That practice is more usually found with datascience packages as they use these interactively in Jupyther notebooks and shorter names matter more.